# Inverse of the Jordan block matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, jordan-normal-form

There is the Jordan block matrix

$J_\lambda(n):=\begin{pmatrix}  \lambda & 1 & & & \\  & \lambda & 1 \\ & & ... & ... \\ & & & \lambda & 1 \\ & & & & \lambda  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{C^{n \times n}}$

How to find the inverse of this matrix?

I tried with the Gauss Jordan Elimination and got

$J_\lambda(n)^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}  \frac{1}{\lambda} & 0 & & & \\  & \frac{1}{\lambda} & 0 \\ & & ... & ... \\ & & & \frac{1}{\lambda} & 0 \\ & & & & \frac{1}{\lambda} \end{pmatrix}$

But i don't know if this works.

Comment: The solution already has been provided. - But the wrongness of your proposal would have been obvious just by calculating the matrix product of those 2 matrices of yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your matrix $J_\lambda(n)=\lambda I+N$ where
$$N=\pmatrix{0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&0
}.$$
Then $N$ is nilpotent: $N^n=0$ and so
$I+tN$ will have the inverse $I-tN+t^2N^2-\cdots +(-t)^{n-1}N^{n-1}$.
Then
$$J_\lambda(n)^{-1}=\lambda^{-1}(1+\lambda^{-1}N)^{-1}
=\lambda^{-1}(I-\lambda^{-1} N+\lambda^{-2}N^2-\cdots +(-\lambda)^{-n+1}N^{n-1}).$$