# Determine the minimal polynomial and inverse of an n-by-n Jordan block

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

Suppose $a \neq 0$, and the n-by-n matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 0 & ...\\ 0 & a & 1 & ...\\ & & ... \\ & & ... & a \end{pmatrix}$$ (that is, $a$ on the diagonal and $1$ on the super-diagonal), with $n>3$.

1. Determine the minimal polynomial of $A$.
2. Provide a simple formula for finding the inverse of $A$ in a systematic way. That is, provide the steps required to systematically determine $A^{-1}$.

I think that I have answered part 1: the minimal polynomial should be (I think) $m_{A}(s) = (s-a)^{n}$, since the size of the block is $n$. But I have no idea what process to use for the second part.

Comment: To get you started: What are the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$? What shape is the inverse of an upper-triangular matrix?

Comment: @amd I believe that the eigenvalues are 1/a, and the inverse of an upper triangular matrix is also upper triangular.

Comment: I was trying to use a binomial expansion of the minimal polynomial to find the inverse, because I know that the inverse can be represented as a polynomial in A, under certain conditions. But that became too messy, and I wasn't sure how to get to a result.

Comment: Try the power series for $(aI+N)^{-1}$ instead. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777793/265466.